# Local differentially private normal vectors

Tags: pr.probability

We're given a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ whose coordinates where sampled from a known normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

How should I send this vector while maintaining (local) differential privacy? with some sensitivity over its $\ell_2$ norm (i.e., two close vectors should not be distinguishable). Is there a way to take the fact that we know the source distribution into account?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess relatively few people here know the concept of *differential privacy* (I do not), so you may get better response if you give a hint what it is all about, or perhaps rephrase your question in more standard terms. (At least, I'd be happy just to understand the question.)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki the definitions are standard by now and I'm not sure it's appropriate to repeat here (also, they're not trivial, and I can't presume to write an easier explanation here, than what is found online). There is a nice self-contained summary in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10559.pdf, Section 2.1 (no need to look anywhere else in the paper).

Comment: OK, thanks for the link, time permitting I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for showing interest in any case